# How to check a CPU's version using CPU-Z?

Tags: cpu

When I use the CPU-Z software to check the CPU information:

there it has a param name `Family`, what's it mean? is it mean the version?

[image]

Such as the `E3-1200 V6`, I want to know the version 6 is which param, is there shows?

Comment: Your CPU isn't being properly identified in that screenshot.  I am 99% sure any modern Intel CPU is going to report the family as being 6 due to all processors being based on the 8086 architecture.